# Checkbox made with Sencha Touch is too large, why

Tags: checkbox, sencha-touch

I want to make a checkbox with Sencha Touch 2. I made it like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    id: 'remember',
    checked: false,
    style:'background-color:white;'
}
```

But I've noticed that it's way too large.

How can I resize the checkbox to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Checkbox

At the top you will find **CSS Vars**

Hover over that entry and you will see

- $form-field-height
- $form-field-input-height

Go into the sass section of Sencha Touch and add these two (as needed) and set the value you need.
(you need to understand SASS and use compass to compile)